# Python: Parsing a class prints nothing?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, mechanize, findall

Trying to parse a weather page and select the weekly forecasted highs.

Normally I would search with `tags = soup.find_all("span", id="hi")` but this tag doesn't use an `id` it uses a `class`.

Full code:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_browser = mechanize.Browser()
html_page = my_browser.open("http://www.wunderground.com/weather-forecast/45056")
html_text = html_page.get_data()
my_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text)

tags = my_soup.find_all("span", class_="hi")

temp = tags[0].string
print temp
```

When I run this, nothing prints

The piece of HTML is buried inside a bunch of other tags, however the specific tag for today's high is as follows:

```
<span class="hi">63</span>
```

Comment: Should I work back up the html tag chain until I get to an 'id' to reference? Then split out everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `class_` as the parameter name. See [the docs.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)

The problem arises because `class` is a Python keyword, so you can't use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to scraping the web page, you could always check out Weather Underground's [API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/). It's free for developers (limited number of calls per day, etc.), but if you're going to be doing a number of lookups, this might be easier in the end.